# How to clear std::ofstream file buffer?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, buffer

I am making a console text editor that continuously saves its content to a text file as text is being written to the editor.

```cpp
FileEditor editor("C://temp/test.txt");

while (true) {
     if (_kbhit()) {
        editor.keypress(_getche());
        system("cls");
        std::cout << editor.content();
        editor.save();
    }
}
```

In order to directly save the written content to the text file without having to `close()` and re`open()` the file everytime, I flush the ofstream file buffer directly after inserting text into it.

```cpp
class FileEditor {
private:
    std::ofstream _file;
    std::string _content;
public:

    // ...

    void save() {
        _file << _content << std::flush;
    }

    // ...

};
```

The problem is when I write multiple characters into the console, for example the string `abcd`, it will write `a` to the file, then `aab`, adding `ab` to the current buffer content, then `aababc`, and so on.

Therefore, I wish to clear the ofstream file buffer to replace its contents instead of continuously adding new text to the buffer. Is there a method for clearing the file buffer? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

I tried finding a method for clearing the buffer and I tried searching online for anyone who might've had the same problem as me, but to no avail.

Comment: if you add _content.clear(); after writing to the file then your problem is gone.

Comment: Once stuff goes into the file stream, there nothing you can do about it. The abstraction that is a stream has no tool for getting data back out again because many streams, a serial port or socket for example, may have already sent the data before you can you try to remove it. A text file on your hard disk file is a kinder case, you can seek backwards and hope you write over the unwanted data in the future, but it still adheres to the behaviour of all streams: no takeses backses.

Comment: Be aware that _getch() and _getche() will result in 0 or 0xE0 for special keys ! See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I write multiple characters into the console, for example the string `abcd`, it will write `a` to the file, then `aab`, adding `ab` to the current buffer content, then `aababc`, and so on.

Your problem has nothing to do with the file buffer.  You are not clearing the editor buffer after writing it to the file, so you are writing the same characters to the file over and over.

The user types `a`, so your editor buffer is `a`, and you write `a` to the file.

Then, the user types `b`, so your editor buffer is now `ab`, and you write `ab` to the file.

Then, the user types `c`, so your editor buffer is now `abc`, and you write `abc` to the file.

Then, the user types `d`, so your editor buffer is now `abcd`, and you write `abcd` to the file.

And so on.

You need to write only the new characters that have entered the editor buffer since the last write to the file.  For instance, maintain an index into the editor buffer where the last file write left off, and then have the next file write pick up from that index and advance it for the next file write, etc.

> Therefore, I wish to clear the `ofstream` file buffer to replace its contents instead of continuously adding new text to the buffer. Is there a method for clearing the file buffer? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

The only way to do this with `ofstream` is to close the re-open the file stream so that the current file content can be truncated.  Otherwise, you will have to resort to using platform-specific APIs to truncate the file without closing it first.